# De file_get_contents a curl

Tags: php, curl

Hola este script me trabaja muy bien con el file_get_contents pero me interesa llevarlo a cur por la rapides de respuesta. He tratado con las diferentes opciones de context, pero por mas que le busco la vuelta no me trae el contenido del archivo remotos, me podrian hechar una mano para convertirlo en curl. Gracias

```
<?php
extension_loaded('openssl') or die('openssl');
$http['method'] = 'POST';
$http['header'] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$http['content'] = <<<eof
{
   "clientid": "lTGjFpjOIP8", "context": {
   "client": {"clientName": "WEB", "clientVersion": "1.19700101"}
   }
}
eof;

$con = stream_context_create(['http' => $http]);
$key = '?key=AIzaSyAO_F';

echo file_get_contents('https://www.server.com/'.$key,false, $con);

?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código con el que intentas pasarlo a cURL y qué problemas o errores tienes al respecto? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Especificamente el Array $http$http['method'] = 'POST';
$http['header'] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$http['content'] = <<<eof
{
   "clientid": "lTGjFpjOIP8", "context": {
   "client": {"clientName": "WEB", "clientVersion": "1.19700101"}
   }
}
eof;

Comment: Eso NO es cURL en absoluto. ¿Leíste la [documentación sobre cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)? Revisa el *Ejemplo básico* y los otros apartados que tienen que ver con las cabeceras y demás.